# How can we fetch data from database in PHP using ajax and display in value of input type?

Tags: php, html, ajax

I am working with two forms where if user submitted first form the data is inserted using ajax to database and user is redirected to second form(Both Forms are in same file).
When user which is present on second form  presses back button the value on the input type text for form1 one to be fetched from db which is stored when user submitted the first form.
My doubt is how can we pass value from ajax call to input type text
Here is my code which i have done uptill now

```
//Form 1
<form  id="titlechange">
<div id="step1">
<input type="text" name="tbl_title" id="title" value="" class="form-control">
 <input type="text" name="tbl_description" id="description" value="" class="form-control">    
  <button type="button" onclick="addTitle()" name="firstsubmit" class="update-btn" >Next</button>                                                
</div>
</form>
//Form 2
<form  id="detailsubmit">
<div id="step2">
<div class = "data"> //input type hidden retreived after submitting from 1 inside class data
<input type="hidden"  value="<?php echo $insertData  ?>" class="form-control">
</div>
<input type="text" name="city" id="city" value="" class="form-control">
 <input type="text" name="state" id="state" value="" class="form-control">    
  <button type="button" onclick="addTitle()" name="firstsubmit" class="update-btn" >Next</button>   
<button type="button" onclick="editModeForStep1()" name="firstsubmit" class="update-btn" >Back</button>                                                
</div>
</form>
```

Ajax Call for back button

```
   function editModeForStep1()
{
  var formData = new FormData($('#detailsubmit')[0]);
             formData.append('action', 'retreive');
    $.ajax({
                 method: 'post',
                 processData: false,
                 contentType: false,
                 cache: false,
                 enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                 url: 'ClientData.php',
                         data: formData,
         
                      success:function(msg){
//what should be written here for displaying value received from `ClientData.php` to value attribute of input type text in form 1 
              $('#step1').addClass('in active');
            alert('success');                     
                     
                 }
             });
}
```

ClientData.php

```
 if(isset($_POST["action"]) && $_POST["action"]=="retreive"){
   
   $insertData = $_POST['insertdata'];
   $slideOne = $objMaster->getSlideForEdit($insertData);
   foreach($slideOne as $key=>$value)
   {
    echo   $title = $value['title'];
      echo $description = $value['description'];
   }
             
   }
```

Comment: What does `msg` contain in your ajax success function? It seems like your code shouldn't work because you are just echoing strings back to aJax which will make it hard to actually use that data.

Comment: Okay. Why do you use a loop on `ClientData.php`? Is there more than 1 title/description that is displayed?

Comment: You can make json in `ClientDate.php` and pass it back to ajax and the via jquery fill your inputs with value. Or you can generate html+data in  `ClientDate.php` and return html

Comment: Yes actually previously when inserting data from form 1 I was  getting insertdata using same method echoing the value and then inside success $(.data).html(msg) due to which i am getting input type hidden in forrm 2.

Comment: @Ingus can you give refrence for the same

Comment: `<input type="hidden"  value="<?php $insertData  ?>" class="form-control">` - That has no value since you didn't echo that variable.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton no it contain only one title and description

Comment: You have 2x `<form>` but only one `</form>`.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner it is there in original code.Editing the same here

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner in original code there are more fields then i have mentioned here due to which i have to edit the same while posting here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let's change `ClientData.php` to return data in a more usable form.

```
if(isset($_POST["action"]) && $_POST["action"]=="retreive"){

    $insertData = $_POST['insertdata'];

    //select first row of results for getSlideForEdit by adding `[0]`
    $slideOne = $objMaster->getSlideForEdit($insertData)[0];
    
    //notice array keys match form1 form elements ID
    //notice there is no need for a loop here
    echo json_encode(
        array(
            'title' => $slideOne['title'], 
            'description' => $slideOne['description']
        )
    );

    //if you want to update EVERYTHING from $slideOne, you can just do
    //echo json_encode($slideOne);
    //instead of the above json_encode()

}
```

Now our return will contain JSON data instead of plain strings. We can update your `success` method to update those input boxes.

```
...
data: formData,

//set dataType to json because we are receiving json from the server
dataType: 'json',
success:function(msg){
    $('#step1').addClass('in active');
    
    //if you don't set dataType to json you can also do
    //msg = JSON.parse(msg);

    //loop through returned array.
    $.each(msg, function(index, value) {
        
        //select element by index e.g `#title`, set value
        $('#' + index).val(value);
    });

    alert('success');                     
}
```

This solution will dynamically update any input on your page as long as you return a `key=>value` pair for it from your server.

Comment: Thanks Grumpy will check and let you know

Comment: what if there is a select type in the form

Comment: How can I then make it's option selected

Comment: @mass It should work the same way. If not, I would need more details about your select element.

Comment: You mena this->  $('#' + index).val(value)  would work for <select> type also

Comment: Yes, it should.